# A start job is running for LSB: raise network interfaces

Tags: raspbian-jessie, boot-issues

I am working with the Raspberry pi 3 with raspbian jessie (not pixel). It is showing me "A start job is running for LSB: raise network interfaces" and taking too much time for complete booting (near about 12-15 mins). After that when I see the desktop, its only showing the "waste basket", cursor but not the "start panel". I am in deep trouble. What should I have to do ?

Comment: Did you make changes to the network config?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your raspberry is waiting for network at boot.
You may try to configure this point by running :
`sudo raspi-config` via SSH.

Choose "Wait for network at boot" then "No".

I doubt this is related to your second problem, but it worth a try :)

Comment: stupid question but how should he run raspi-config on a machine that does not boot. You may want to suggest SSH.